# Can I use Logical operators inside a delimeter [ ] or use 2 delimeters in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, interpolation

My co-worker says I cannot use Logical operators inside square [ ] bracket delimeters inside angular. But when I use it works perfectly fine. Is there any reason behind it? For example,

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of formfield.value" [value]="option.CountryCode || option.CountryName">{{option.CountryCode}} {{option.CountryName}}

is the above code written correctly or should I change syntax usage?

I tried to use 2 delimeters inside same tag with a logical operator added to it.

Comment: `[value]="option.CountryCode || option.CountryName"` would behave 100% the same as `[value]="option.CountryCode"` if all `CountryCode` fields are truthy = not null or 0 or undefined

Comment: @Andrej: I work with || operators and  `[value]="option.CountryCode || option.CountryName"` works like a charm. If "CountryCode" is undefined, the text will be "CountryName".

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way I can call data that is being stored in a typescript file into html using delimeters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"> <mat-option *ngFor="let option of formfield.value" [value]="option.CountryCode || option.CountryName">{{option.CountryCode}} {{option.CountryName}}

This is okay, but for more readability you can use method and return the result like below.

[value]="getOptionValue(option)";

in .ts file please add the method :

getOptionValue(option : any): string{
  return ( option.CountryCode || option.CountryName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. And it is ok. But you can't use expressions they have side effects. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-overview) you can read all about it.

Well, a simple logical or `||` or a expression like this: `[dataField]='company.name ? company.name : "Select a company."'` are absolutely ok.

[image]